# Scraping a website using PHP "Simple HTML Dom Parser" for data

Tags: php, web-scraping, web

I'm trying to use the PHP Simple DOM Parser to pull information from a website and it isn't working for me.

Specifically i am trying to get the:

1. 5-day prediction
2. 1-month prediction

values from the top of the page.

i am trying to grab the results from this div _ngcontent-coincodex-c2362887433 but not able to extract the data.

no errors encountered. Just not able to get the intended value.

This is my code.

```
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
$url = 'https://coincodex.com/crypto/bad-idea-ai/price-prediction';
$html = file_get_html($url);

foreach($html->find('div._ngcontent-coincodex-c2362887433') as $article) {
    echo 'Output:' .$article;   
}
```

Grateful if anyone can share with me what I am doing wrong here.

this is the html i m trying to scrape:

```
<div _ngcontent-coincodex-c2362887433="" placment="top" tooltipclass="tooltip-custom-class" class="prediction-range" aria-describedby="ngb-tooltip-9">
  <div _ngcontent-coincodex-c2362887433="">5-Day Prediction
  </div>
  <div _ngcontent-coincodex-c2362887433="">
    <i _ngcontent-coincodex-c2362887433="" appfontawesome="" class="far fa-long-arrow-down">
    <svg style="pointer-events: none;" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 320 512" class="svg-inline--fa"><path fill="currentColor" d="M300.3 327.5l-19.6-19.6c-4.8-4.8-12.5-4.7-17.1.2L186 388.8V44c0-6.6-5.4-12-12-12h-28c-6.6 0-12 5.4-12 12v344.8l-77.5-80.7c-4.7-4.8-12.4-4.9-17.1-.2l-19.6 19.6c-4.7 4.7-4.7 12.3 0 17l131.8 131.8c4.7 4.7 12.3 4.7 17 0l131.8-131.8c4.6-4.7 4.6-12.3-.1-17z"></path>
    </svg>
    </i> $ 0.0₇3329 <!----><!----><!---->
  </div><!----><!----><!----><!----><!---->
</div>
```

Comment: `it isn't working for me` is a bit vague, don't you think?

Comment: We can't see the html you're trying to scrape. Please provide a [mre] of the issue. Then we'll be happy to try and help. See also [ask], and remember we can't see your screen. You can [edit] your post. Thanks

Comment: i am trying to grab the results from this div _ngcontent-coincodex-c2362887433 but not able to extract the data.

Comment: Thanks. Your selector is written as if `_ngcontent...` etc is a class in the element, but it's an attribute all by itself

Comment: thanks. any idea how i can grab the value as an attribute? appreciate any guidance as i m new to web scrapping.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your scraping by looking for the class `.prediciton-range`, and then grabbing only the elements with unlocked information:

```
<?php

/*

Question Author: Blackstone
Question Answerer: Jacob Mulquin
Question: Scraping a website using PHP "Simple HTML Dom Parser" for data
URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77505951/scraping-a-website-using-php-simple-html-dom-parser-for-data
Tags: , php, web-scraping, web

*/

require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

if (!file_exists('prices.html')) {
  $url = 'https://coincodex.com/crypto/bad-idea-ai/price-prediction';
  $html = file_get_html($url);
  file_put_contents('prices.html', $html);
} else {
  $html = file_get_html('prices.html');
}

foreach($html->find('.prediction-range') as $article) {
    $plain_text = $article->plaintext;
    $split = explode('$', $plain_text);

    // Ignore "Prediction unlock" entries
    if (count($split) == 1)
      continue;

    $prediction_range = $split[0];
    $price = $split[1];

    echo 'Output: ' . $prediction_range . ' = ' . $price . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Output: 5-Day Prediction  =  0.0₇3326 
Output: 1-Month Prediction  =  0.0₇3953
```

Comment: thank you Jacob!! It works like a charm. :)

Comment: @Blackstone If this answer solved your problem please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it when you can so it can be closed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Rather than looking for the weird `_ngcontent-coincodex-c2362887433`, which number may change in the future, it is safer to look for something more static.

I would recommend looking for the class `prediction-range` like this:

```php
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
$url = 'https://coincodex.com/crypto/bad-idea-ai/price-prediction';
$html = file_get_html($url);

$predictions = $html->find('.prediction-range');
$fiveDayPrediction = $predictions[0]->children(1)->plaintext;
$oneMonthPrediction = $predictions[1]->children(1)->plaintext;

echo 'Five day prediction: ' . $fiveDayPrediction . '<br>';
echo 'One month prediction: ' . $oneMonthPrediction . '<br>';
```